# How dependency injection works for Interfaces in constructors

Tags: magento2, dependency-injection

As far as I know you can set a preference for an Interface in the **`di.xml`** of an extension.
But i see several Interfaces without any reference in the `di.xml`.
How are these instantiated?

Examples:
*[app/code/Magento/Directory/Model/ResourceModel/Country/Collection.php](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Directory/Model/ResourceModel/Country/Collection.php)*

The constructor contains that code:

```
 \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface $connection = null,
```

or
*app/code/Magento/Payment/Model/Info.php*

```
\Magento\Framework\Encryption\EncryptorInterface $encryptor
```

Answer (score 3):

the preference for `\Magento\Framework\Encryption\EncryptorInterface` is set int [`app/etc/di.xml`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/etc/di.xml#L113). That file is not module dependent but it is merged with the other `di.xml` files.
The `$connection` parameter defaults to `null`. This means that if it's not specified, the DI container will not try to instantiate the preference for `\Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface`. Instead it will just use null for this.

Comment: Thanks Marius i was missing the [app/etc/di.xml](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/etc/di.xml#L113) My issue is that i am getting a fatal error in my collection class, using the **AdapterInterface** in my constructor Fatal error: Cannot instantiate interface Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface Any idea?