# What preference to use for \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface?

Tags: magento2, dependency-injection

I'm trying to override a Collection constructor and getting

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface in /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 93
```

As well as

```
Error: Cannot instantiate interface Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface in /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 93
```

I have tried:

1. Look in the core for any preference for `Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface` with no luck.
2. setup:di:compile with no luck.

The problem was also raised here: 
[How dependency injection works for Interfaces in constructors](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/103465/how-dependency-injection-works-for-interfaces-in-constructors) with no answer though.

Any help will much appreciated.

EDIT

So the problem was not overriding the Collection constructor.

class Collection extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection
{

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface $entityFactory,
    \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
    \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy,
    \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager,
    \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface $connection = null,
    \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb $resource = null,
     $someParam = null
)
{
    parent::__construct($entityFactory, $logger, $fetchStrategy, $eventManager, $connection, $resource);
    //$this->relationResourceModel = $resourceModel;
}
```

This will work.
The problem was that I was trying to inject a foreign resource model in the collection constructor

class Collection extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection
{
    protected $relationResourceModel;

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface $entityFactory,
    \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
    \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy,
    \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager,
    \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface $connection = null,
    \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb $resource = null,
    \Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\ResourceModel $resourceModel
)
{
    parent::__construct($entityFactory, $logger, $fetchStrategy, $eventManager, $connection, $resource);
    $this->relationResourceModel = $resourceModel;
}
```

This will not work.
It would be nice to know the inner workings of this and why this does not work. But I chosen another approach.

Comment: can you provide code what you have tried so far

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Note that when using default arguments, any defaults should be on the
>   right side of any non-default arguments; otherwise, things will not
>   work as expected.

http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php

Moreover, in this case `connection` with type `\Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface` is non-injectable object.

> Newable/non-injectable: Objects obtained by creating a new class
>   instance every time. Transient objects, such as those that require
>   external input from the user or database, fall into this category.
>   Attempts to inject these objects produce either an error that the
>   object could not be created or an incorrect object that is incomplete.

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/depend-inj.html

Try to move required arguments before optional

Answer (score 5):

You can also just remove `\Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface` from `__constructor` and for `parent::__construct` just write **null**